# What's the possible reason for navigator.serviceWorker.register error？

Tags: service-worker

I register service worker like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
    scope: '/'
}).then(function(registration) {}).catch(function(err) {console.log(err)})
```

In production environment, I caught some errors like `The request to fetch the script was interrupted.` and `The Service Worker system has shutdown.`
What's the possible reasons for above errors?

---

There is a comment explaining them. I think it is useful.  https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1275

Comment: can you share screenshot of project directory with `sw.js`

Comment: My service worker is on the root of one domain just like `http://localhost:8080/sw.js`

Comment: Just try by replacing `/sw.js` to `sw.js`...!

Answer (score 0):

Its because the path to your service worker might not be correct. If your service worker is on the same level as the page which is trying to load the service worker then do `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js'})`. `/sw.js` tries to load from the root of the project for e.g. `http://localhost:8080/sw.js`. Also look at network logs in the developer console to figure out the path the browser is using to fetch the service worker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My service worker is on the root of one domain just like `http://localhost:8080/sw.js`, and it works fine in major scenes like Chrome 64.0.3282.119 on PC. The errors in my question occurred to some phones. Is compatibility caused by it?

Comment: Not sure if service workers are supported in all phone browsers.